# SAS Missing value replacement

Tags: sas, missing-data

Suppose I have variables X1, X2, X3, and Group in a dataset. Group has distinct values, say 1-10, and X1, X2, X3 are continuous variables. X1, X2, and X3 has missing values sprinkled throughout the dataset, independent of each other. In other words, X1 could be missing but not X2 and X3, and another observation could be missing just X3.

For each missing value, I would like to replace it with the median value of that variable within that observation's Group #.

Is there any good way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For achieving your result then @Joe's answer is the way to go. I'd also recommend looking at PROC MI (Multiple Imputation).  This enables more complex methods to be used, which may be better for the purpose of the task, e.g. statistical modelling

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach here is multi-step:

1. Calculate medians by group (using PROC MEANS or similar analytic procedure)
2. Merge onto the main dataset by group, with a new variable (say "x3_median" etc.)
3. In that datastep or a succeeding one, `x3 = coalesce(x3,x3_median);` and similar for x1 and x2.

You could do 2 and 3 in a single datastep or in a single PROC SQL join.  You theoretically can calculate the median in one SQL step and append it, but that likely would be slower and much harder to maintain (as median is a relatively difficult calculation for SQL to do and cannot be done directly with a function - the MEDIAN function is not an aggregation function in SQL).